# Image follows screen while scrolling

Tags: html, css, image, jpeg

**FIXED: FORGOT TO CLOSE DIVS, MY BAD**
I am having extensive trouble getting an image to stay in place when scrolling downwards, sort of going off the screen when the user of the webpage scrolls down. The solutions in which i have tried is setting the image position to retaliative, absolute and resizing, here is my current code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="baseofcasestudies.css"/>
</head>
<body>
```

```js
function openSlideMenu(){
document.getElementById('slide-menu').style.width = '250px';
}

function closeSlideMenu(){
document.getElementById('slide-menu').style.width = '0';
document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '0';
}
```

```css
body{
font-family: "Arial", Serif;
overflow-y: visible;
width: 1024px;
height: 1200px;
background-attachment: absolute;
}
.side-nav{
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #111;
opacity: 0.9;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 60px;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.side-nav a{
padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 22px;
display: block;
color: #ccc;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.side-nav a:hover{
color: #fff;
}
.navbar{
position: fixed;
top: 10;
left: 10;
z-index: 1;
}
#myVideo{
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -50;
}
.Tri{
position: absolute;
transform: rotate(-270deg);
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
z-index: 5;
margin-top: 250;
margin-left: 300;
}
.Tri:hover{
transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.data{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.5;
height: 1200px;
width: 1200px;
transform: translate(25%, 5%);
}
.titleofstudy{
position: absolute;
left: 75%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
font-size: 70px;
color: white;
}
html css image jpeg
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
      <source src="background2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="open-slide">
    <a herf="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
    <svg width="30" height="30">
    <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000"
    stroke-width="5"/>
    <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000"
    stroke-width="5"/>
    <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000"
    stroke-width="5"/>
    </svg>
    </a>
    </span>


    <div id="slide-menu" class="side-nav">
    <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </div>
    
    <div class="Tri" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
    <svg height="30" width="30">
    <polygon points="8.3,2 3.3,13.3 13.3,13.3"             
    style="fill:black;stroke:none;stroke-width:0" />
    </svg>
    </div>
    <p class="titleofstudy">Case Study Name</p>
    </div>
    <img src="black.jpg" class="data">
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS.

```
html{
}
body{
font-family: "Arial", Serif;
overflow-y: visible;
width: 1024px;
height: 1200px;
background-attachment: absolute;
}
.side-nav{
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #111;
opacity: 0.9;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 60px;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.side-nav a{
padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 22px;
display: block;
color: #ccc;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.side-nav a:hover{
color: #fff;
}
.navbar{
position: fixed;
top: 10;
left: 10;
z-index: 1;
}
#myVideo{
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -50;
}
.Tri{
position: absolute;
transform: rotate(-270deg);
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
z-index: 5;
margin-top: 250;
margin-left: 300;
}
.Tri:hover{
transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.data{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.5;
height: 1200px;
width: 1200px;
transform: translate(25%, 5%);
}
.titleofstudy{
position: absolute;
left: 75%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
font-size: 70px;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you first check you html and css with validators [html](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) [css](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) Copy you code there click check. You have some mistakes.

Comment: Thank you sir, i forgot to close the Nav bar, stupid mistake from my behalf.

Comment: Your code has so many issues man but anyways. What you're looking for is position: fixed; https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp